# ObjectiveC - Extend already initialized object

Tags: objective-c, object, inheritance

Surely dumb question but I did a class called `GLManagedObject` that extends `NSManagedObject`.

I have a `NSManagedObject` already initialized that I'd like to extend with my custom methods:

```c
NSManagedObject *mo = [someclass getAnInitializedMO];
[(GLManagedObject *)mo myCustomMethod];
```

How can I use `myCustonMethod` with `mo` ?

---

I tried to add an initializer method

```c
+ (MGLManagedObject *)initWithMO:(NSManagedObject *)mo
{
    return (MGLManagedObject *)[mo copy];
}
```

But it's telling `copyWithZone` is unrecognized.

Comment: Create a custom 
+ (id)glManagedObjectWithManagedObject:(NSManagedObject*)managedObject; or - (id)initWithManagedObject:(NSManagedObject*)managedObject; in GLManagedObject that will copy managedObject into a new object.

Comment: Another approach to the problem would have been to add myCustomMethod to NSManagedOject in a category. If you don't need new properties or instance variables.

Comment: You need to override the copy method (actually the copyWithZone method) because apparently you are counting on NSObject to do the job for you and it won't. You need to do the copy manually.

Comment: No chance for you to use a category??

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I need to handle properties too.

Comment: Doesn't NSManagedObject already have it's own implementation of `copy` ? That's the one I'm trying to use, am I not ?

Comment: No, it doesn't: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html It inherits NSObject copy method, but that won't do it.